# BeginGetResponse from BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono, webrequest

I am creating a webrequest both from the UI thread and a `BackgroundWorker` thread.

```
IAsyncResult result = request.BeginGetResponse (o => {
    callCallback (o);
}, state);
```

....

```
private void callCallback (IAsyncResult o)
{
    RequestStateGen state = (RequestStateGen)o.AsyncState;
    state.context.Post (_ => {
        onGetCustomListObject (o);
    }, null);
}
```

When I call this code from the UI thread it works fine. When called from the `BackgroundWorker` thread it freezes on BeginGetResponse.

The UI is still responsive. Any thoughts?

**Edit:** I figured out that I actually not need the UI context when calling from my background thread. And I think it would've been really hard injecting a ui context that always is valid. Here is my code now that works:

```
private void callCallback (IAsyncResult o)
{
    RequestStateGen state = (RequestStateGen)o.AsyncState;
    if (!state.OnBgThread)
        {
            state.context.Post (_ => {
                onGetCustomListObject (o);
            }, null);
        }
        else
        {
            onGetCustomListObject (o);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is reliant on `SynchronizationContext.Current` grabbing the UI context.  If you're already in a background thread then that context will not be the UI's context.

You can call `BeginGetResponse` from a background thread just fine, but you need to ensure that `SynchronizationContext.Current` is called from the UI thread and somehow exposed to your background thread.

Comment: I figured out that I don't need the UI context for my callback when called from BackgroundWorker. It would also be very hard to inject the UI context. But same problem as before. Even if I remove the UI context it freezes on BeginGetResponse when called from BackgroundWorker. See my updated answer.

Comment: Problem solved. I did not set the OnBgThread variable correctly.

Comment: @Sunkas Good to hear; I wasn't sure what could be wrong with your change based on what you showed.